# TASM code for multiples of n under 100 doesnt show output

Tags: assembly, tasm

This is what the code does. Say the user inputs the number 20. it multiplies this with the counter CX, set to 1, and increases for each iteration. when the result reaches or exceeds 100 (4 iterations for the number 20) it goes back and prints all of them by pushing and popping into the stack.
Each number is added, then separated to single digits, and then displayed using the 02 function.

```
MOV CX, 01D
MOV AX, 0
MOV DX, BX ; BX contains the number 
MOV DI, 01 ;
MOV SI, 01 ;  used for addressing offsets of BX 


MULTIPLY: 
MOV AX, DX  
MUL CX
CMP AX, 100D
JGE FINISHED
MOV [BX+DI], AX
INC CX
INC DI ; will be changed to ADD DI, 2
JMP MULTIPLY
```

This snippet has the problem. Im trying to get this to multiply the input with 1, then 2 then 3 and so on until the result reaches 100. What have I missed here?

Comment: Hi, double check your register usage (BX is initialized with...?) and your dimensions (AX is 16 bits, `inc di` is not enough). As it's currently standing this question is off-topic: it is a debug request. You can make it on-topic by: 1) Commenting cleverly 2) Removing all the code you have tested to work 3) Introducing appropriate sub routines 4) Crafting an [mcve] out of all of this 5) Looking for duplicates 6) Realizing that steps 1-5 actually answered the question on their own. I know debugging assembly is hard, don't give up!

Comment: In MULTIPLY: loop you initialize AX with DX, which holds upper 16 bits of previous multiplication (zero in most cases, so your loop will never finish). As you work with positive numbers and unsigned multiplications, you should also prefer unsigned compare (JAE instead of JGE).

Comment: Thanks a lot @MargaretBloom

Comment: @vitsoft thank you. I had forgotten that DX was used it MUL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem in your code : before label `multiply` you store the input number in DX :

```
MOV DX, BX ; BX contains the number
```

but after the label `multiply` you use `mul`, that destroys DX. The solution is to use another register, BP for example, instead of DX.

Another important problem is that you are storing the multiples in `[BX+DI]`, but there is no variable in the data segment where BX is pointing to. The solution is to create an array ("buf").

Now let's apply both solutions to your **original** code, I added a comma to separate the numbers, changes are pointed by arrows (`;<===`) :

```
 .MODEL  SMALL
 .STACK  100H
 .DATA

  S1 DB 13,10, "Enter a number below 100  :" , '$' 
  S3 DB 13,10, "The multiples are: ", '$'
  buf dw 100 dup(?)    ;<=== ARRAY OF MULTIPLES.
  comma db ",$"        ;<=== SEPARATOR BETWEEN MULTIPLES ON SCREEN.

  .CODE
  MAIN PROC 
  MOV AX,@DATA
  MOV DS,AX

LEA DX, S1
MOV AH, 09 ; ENTER A NUMBER?
INT 21H

CALL INPUT ;ACCEPTS A NUMBER

LEA DX, S3
MOV AH, 09 ; THE MULTIPLES ARE:
INT 21H
MOV CX, 01D
MOV AX, 0
MOV bp, BX             ;<=== PRESERVE INPUT NUMBER IN BP.
mov di, offset buf     ;<=== DI POINTS TO ARRAY OF MULTIPLES.
;MOV DI, 01
;MOV SI, 01


MULTIPLY:  ;where the good stuff happens
MOV AX, BP            ;<=== MUL WILL CHANGE DX, THAT'S WHY WE USE BP.
MUL CX                ;AX*CX = RESULT IN DX:AX.
CMP AX, 100D
JGE FINISHED
MOV [di], AX           ;<=== STORE MULTIPLE IN ARRAY.
INC CX
;INC DI
add di,2               ;<=== EACH MULTIPLE IS TWO BYTES.
JMP MULTIPLY

FINISHED:   

;WHEN PREVIOUS BLOCK FINISHES "DI" POINTS AT THE END OF "BUF".

;MOV CX, 0             ;<=== CX IS ZERO 6 LINES BELOW.
MOV DX,0
MOV BX,10D

mov si, offset buf     ;<=== SI POINTS TO THE ARRAY OF MULTIPLES.
OUTER:
MOV CX, 0              ;<=== CX MUST BE HERE (IT'S DIGIT COUNTER).
MOV AX,[SI]            ;<=== RETRIEVE A MULTIPLE FROM ARRAY.
SHOW:            ;push to stack and print digit by digit     
MOV DX,0 
DIV BX                       
PUSH DX                       
INC CX                       
CMP AX,0                       
JNZ SHOW
PRINT:                     
MOV DX,0                      
MOV AH,02H                      
POP DX                      
ADD DL,30H                      
INT 21H
LOOP PRINT
;DISPLAY COMMA SEPARATOR.
  mov ah,9
  mov dx,offset comma
  int 21h
;INC SI
add si, 2              ;<=== NEXT MULTIPLE TO DISPLAY.
CMP SI, DI             ;<=== IF SI IS NOT IN THE END
JNE OUTER

INPUT PROC
ACCEPT:
MOV AH,01H
INT 21H                  

CMP AL,0DH
JZ CONTINUE

MOV AH,0
SUB AL,30H
PUSH AX
MOV AX,10D
MUL BX

POP BX
ADD BX,AX
JMP ACCEPT
CONTINUE:
RET
INPUT ENDP

EXIT:
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
ENDP MAIN
END MAIN
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough. It was beginning to drive me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

I sort of wonder why do you use even MUL for this (unless you really had because of assignment rules). In case this would be real problem in production, you could write the whole thing in much simpler way, for example:

```
    ...
    ; bx = input number (valid 1..99)

    ; prepare es:di for STOS instruction to store results
    MOV     ax,@DATA
    MOV     es,ax
    MOV     di,OFFSET multipliedNumbers
    CLD
    ; init loop variables
    XOR     ax,ax
    XOR     cx,cx
multiplyLoop:
    ADD     ax,bx   ; calculate next result
    CMP     ax,100
    JGE     endMultiplyLoop
    STOSW           ; store result
    INC     cx      ; counting results
    JMP     multiplyLoop
endMultiplyLoop:
    ; multipliedNumbers array contains cx numbers

    ...

    ; BTW, to process them, set ds:si to results array
    MOV     si,OFFSET multipliedNumbers
        ; I assume ds already points to @DATA here
        ; and DF is still 0 (no STD since CLD)
    ; cx should be still number of stored results
readNumbersLoop:
    LODSW   ; ax = number, si+=2
    ; do whatever you want with ax *here*
    ; but keep ds:si and cx intact (or PUSH/POP them)
    LOOP readNumbersLoop

.DATA
multipliedNumbers   DW  100 DUP (?)
```

While this variant is by no means top performer on modern days CPU, it should be quite "human" readable and not that hard to understand. I loved to use STOS/LODS in these situations, as they save you from bugs like your original `INC DI` instead of `ADD DI,2`.

I felt sort of sad when I realized somewhere around Pentium/686 the straightforward `MOV [di],ax ADD di,2` was faster (especially when interleaved with other ops). Just like nowadays people use `ADD reg,1` instead of `INC`. Poor Increment, being here pretty much from the very beginning of CPUs and now being left useless... ;) :D

---

Edit:

In case you really had to use `MUL`, then you sort of failed to do your home work (using `dx` together with `MUL r16`) :/.

Have an instruction reference guide at hand, and keep checking the details of instructions often (like which flags are exactly affected, etc).

Also it helps to read trough all of them from time to time, if you ever happen to do some 256B intros, recalling weird things like `XLAT` can make whole world difference (between fitting into those 256 bytes, or not).

The original reference guide book delivered with TASM was ultra handy, small and short, based on Intel docs, and including already 386 instructions in my revision. I'm afraid I forgot to return it back to uni, because I used it so much...

Comment: This reminds me of our initial test at uni at programming class: "write a program to display squares of first n numbers (from 1).". I had it first and no multiply was used. ( `sq=add=1; while (n--) { print sq; add+=2; sq+=add; }` ). Everyone else from our class did use multiply to calculate the square. :D

Comment: Im a beginner at assembly, cut me some slack here :) thanks, I learnt something new.